# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type: DI won't register the interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm new to Web API/MVC, Autofac, and DI so I'm sure I've got a mess on my hands.

I have a controller in which I am trying to inject a service interface dependency.

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/gameboard")]
    public class GameBoardController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly IGameBoardService _service;
        private ApplicationDbContext _con = new ApplicationDbContext();


        public GameBoardController(IGameBoardService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        /*
        Routes
        */
    }
```

The controller implements a base controller:

```
 public class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {

        private ModelFactory _modelFactory;
        private ApplicationUserManager _AppUserManager = null;
        private ApplicationRoleManager _AppRoleManager = null;

        protected ApplicationUserManager AppUserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _AppUserManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
        }

        public BaseApiController()
        {

        }

        protected ModelFactory TheModelFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_modelFactory == null)
                {
                    _modelFactory = new ModelFactory(this.Request, this.AppUserManager);
                }
                return _modelFactory;
            }
        }

        protected IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (result.Errors != null)
                {
                    foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                    }
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected ApplicationRoleManager AppRoleManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _AppRoleManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            }
        }
    }
```

When making any call to a route in the GameBoardController that uses the `_service` , I get the following error:

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'GameBoardController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
  "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "stackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
  "innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Type 'LearningAngular.Api.Controllers.GameBoardController' does not have a default constructor",
    "exceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
  }
}
```

If I make a call to a route that does NOT use the service, it works fine.

I'm using Autofac to handle my DI and I have tried countless different attempts to get `IGameBoardService` registered for use; to the point that I have pretty much exhausted anything I could think to search on SO or Google.

Of course, if I do what the error says and add the parameterless constructor, the error goes away, but `_service` is always null.

Currently, this is how I have my Autofac configured. I have a config class to handle all of the registrations:

```
public class AutofacConfig
    {
        public static IContainer RegisterAutoFac()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            AddMvcRegistrations(builder);
            AddRegisterations(builder);

            var container = builder.Build();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            return container;
        }

        private static void AddMvcRegistrations(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            //mvc
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

            //web api
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
            builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
        }

        private static void AddRegisterations(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<GameBoardService>().As<IGameBoardService>();
            builder.RegisterModule(new StandardModule());
        }
    }
```

And the StandardModule is as follows:

```
public class StandardModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);

            // obtain database connection string once and reuse by Connection class
            var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"];

            // Register Connection class and expose IConnection 
            // by passing in the Database connection information
            builder.RegisterType<Connection>() // concrete type
                .As<IConnection>() // abstraction
                .WithParameter("settings", conn)
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            // Register Repository class and expose IRepository
            builder.RegisterType<Repository>()
                .As<IRepository>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<GameBoardService>()
                .As<IGameBoardService> ()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
```

Then in my WebApiConfig I make a call to `AutofacConfig.RegisterAutoFac();`

If I put a breakpoint in the AutofacConfig, it gets hit on startup so I know it's running through it. From all of the information I have gathered, I think I have everything I need, but obviously I can't get it to work. It's probably my unfamiliarity with everything that has me missing something, but I'm at a loss. I've following examples and tutorials and multiple SO threads, but nothing works.

What am I missing here in order to make `_service` usable in my controller?

Extra Information - I don't know if it is needed or not, but here is my GameBoardService and its interface:

```
public class GameBoardService : IGameBoardService
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repo;
        private GameBoardHelper gameBoard;
        private Cache cache = new Cache();

        public GameBoardService(IRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public bool createGameBoard()
        {
            gameBoard = new GameBoardHelper();
            cache.insertCacheItem("GameBoard", gameBoard);

            return true;
        }

        public List<Card> playCard(int slot, Card card)
        {
            gameBoard = (GameBoardHelper)cache.getCacheItemByName("GameBoard");

            return gameBoard.playCard(slot, card);
        }

        public bool setHand(int player, List<Card> cardList)
        {
            gameBoard = (GameBoardHelper)cache.getCacheItemByName("GameBoard");

            gameBoard.setHand(player, cardList);
            return true;
        }

        public int getTurn()
        {
            gameBoard = (GameBoardHelper)cache.getCacheItemByName("GameBoard");

            return gameBoard.turn;
        }

        public void setTurn(int player)
        {
            gameBoard = (GameBoardHelper)cache.getCacheItemByName("GameBoard");
            gameBoard.turn = player;
        }

        public Slot opponentTurn()
        {
            gameBoard = (GameBoardHelper)cache.getCacheItemByName("GameBoard");

            return gameBoard.opponentTurn();
        }


        public async Task<IEnumerable<GameBoard>> GetGameBoardAsync()
        {
            // execute the stored procedure called GetEmployees
            return await _repo.WithConnection(async c =>
            {
                // map the result from stored procedure to Employee data model
                var results = await c.QueryAsync<GameBoard>("GetEmployees", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                return results;
            });
        }
    }

public interface IGameBoardService
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<GameBoard>> GetGameBoardAsync();
        bool createGameBoard();
        List<Card> playCard(int slot, Card card);
        bool setHand(int player, List<Card> cardList);
        int getTurn();
        void setTurn(int player);
        Slot opponentTurn();
    }
```

Comment: Did you miss builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); ?
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#quick-start

Answer (score 0):

As [christophe.chapron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333062/christophe-chapron) mentioned, you need to register you API controllers separately to the MVC controllers with the following line:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly‌​());
```

as described in [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#quick-start).